# How can I make my MySQL table save a float up to 20 digits?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Here is my table:
[image]

Let us suppose I want my account balance to be:

```
0.4729472846758294728572
```

So I tried to set it to it but it keeps cutting it off and rounding up.
[image]

How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FLOAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) values are approximate:

> The `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` types represent approximate numeric data values.

If you need arbitrary precision you can use a [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) column instead, e.g. `DECIMAL(25, 20)`. In this case you'll get 5 digits before the decimal and 20 after.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.
see here:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html,
http://code.rohitink.com/2013/06/12/mysql-integer-float-decimal-data-types-differences/